# Find all foreign key rows from table that is referenced multiple times

Tags: sql

I have the following database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE LookupTable
(
    PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
)

CREATE TABLE MainTable
(
    Lookup1 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LookupTable(PK),
    Lookup2 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LookupTable(PK),
    -- ...
    -- ... LookupN UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LookupTable(PK),
)
```

MainTable references LookupTable multiple times via separate columns.

If I insert the following data:

```
INSERT INTO LookupTable VALUES('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111')
INSERT INTO LookupTable VALUES('22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222')
INSERT INTO MainTable VALUES('11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111','22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222')
INSERT INTO MainTable VALUES('22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222','11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111')
```

I want to be able to find every record in [MainTable] where ANY of the lookup fields is equal to '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' (this should return both rows in the example).

SQL is not my strong suit. Is there a simpler way of doing this than

```
SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE
Lookup1 = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
OR
Lookup2 = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
-- ...
-- OR
-- LookupN = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
```

?

This seems tedious because it requires me to specify every lookup column by name before I can retrieve the results I want, and in my database there can be 20+ lookup columns in some circumstances.

Comment: You are feeling the pain of a denormalized design.

Comment: @RedFilter, No, denormalized is usually easier to work with. I don't know what you would call this.

Comment: @Mark SQLDev: see [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), [Repeating groups across columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_across_columns)

Comment: @Mark, buddy, you need to consider a new user id.  This is a classic failure of normalization and exemplifies the reason why denormalized data is generally harder to work with (some exceptions exist, of course).

Comment: If you have control of your database structure, please stop now and normalize your database structure.  If you start down this road you're just making enormous quantities of work (and guaranteeing a system that doesn't perform well) in the future.  Jan tells you what to do, below.

Comment: To categorically blame denormalization is misleading since most of the time, denormalization makes querying easier, not more difficult. That's all I'm trying to say. This is an extreme example and very seldom seen in the wild.

Comment: @Larry, I've worked with databases for almost 15 years and most of my frustration is trying to join some 15 tables or so without creating duplicates or other messes. I more often see extreme normalization than the opposite.

Comment: @Mark, this is not an extreme example, I answer about one of these per day.  A properly constructed database (with keys) does not produce false duplicate records and the additional complexity of querying from more than one table can generally be dealt with using views.  Normalization provides correctness, which is more important than ease-of-querying.

Comment: @Larry, it may be more common to see examples like this here, but I'm talking about seeing them in a business environment.  Normalization isn't bad if it's not taken too far - I'll agree with that.  They say to normalize 'till it hurts, then dial it back (i.e., denormailize) some.  That sounds about right.

Comment: @Mark, it sounded like you were advocating denormalization as a first principle of design.  I can largely agree with the "'til it hurts" policy, as long as a priority is placed on correctness.  And I have to say that pretty much _every single table_ I see designed by a non-programmer that could possibly include this kind of denormalization does, in fact, have it (HomePhone and WorkPhone being the most obvious).

Comment: As long as we don't go crazy creating different tables for work phone and home phone - I've seen normalized tables just as bad. :o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three options:

- Query your tables the way you doing (many ORs)
- Build your query dynamically and execute it (like EXEC on SQL Server)
- Change your database schema and move the Lookup-columns from your MainTable to a third table

---

```
CREATE TABLE LookupTable
(
    PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
)


CREATE TABLE MainTable
(
    PK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
)

CREATE TABLE MainTableLookup
(
    MainTablePK UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MainTable(PK),
    Lookup UNIQUEIDENTIFIER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES LookupTable(PK),
)
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
    MainTable MT JOIN MainTableLookup ON MT.PK = MTL.MainTablePK
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LookupTable LT 
            WHERE LT.PK = MTL.Lookup
                  AND MTL.Lookup = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111')
```

Comment: Additionally, you could add a `Type` column to `MainTableLookup` if you wish, to distinguish between value usages.

Comment: Yes, that might be a valuable addition

Comment: I would number these in reverse order.  And then consider the last two only if the first one is impossible.

Comment: @Larry, its just an unordered list (no priorities) :) And maybe he cant't change his schema

Answer (score 0):

One further suggestion. Doing a query with OR can lead to poor performance; it can be faster with a UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE
Lookup1 = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
UNION
SELECT * FROM MainTable WHERE
Lookup2 = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'
...
```